# How to write script file to run MingW

Tags: c++, windows, path, mingw

I am trying to compile some programs from source and use `MinGW` to compile them.

In the documentation, it recommends using a script file to do it, to avoid permanently adding the `MinGW` program to the `PATH` variable.

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the best way to implement this script file?  Just write a `.bat` file and change details (ie location of source files, etc.) before each use?

2) What is the best way to get and set the `PATH` variable programatically?  Is there some way I can write a script along these lines:

```
oldPath = getCurrentPath()
newPath = oldPath + "; c:/MingGW/bin"
setCurrentPath(newPath)

make ...
make install...
...

setCurrentPath(oldPath)
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: I would just put Mingw32 in the PATH, alot easier, then you can just use a makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `.bat` file will look like here

```
SETLOCAL
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\bin
echo %PATH%
rem your commands here insrtead of echo
```

due to `SETLOCAL` path will be restored after bath file finished. If you want interactive session, just write

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\bin
```

in console window. You will have `PATH` altered in the current console session (not globally) until you close console.